# How can i parse a text between two strings?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method:

```
private static string ExtractFromString(string text, string startString, string endString)
        {
            string matched= "";
            int index = 0;
            int index1 = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                index = text.IndexOf(startString);
                index1 = text.IndexOf(endString, index);
                matched = text.Substring(index + startString.Length,
                                         index1 - index - startString.Length);
                index = text.IndexOf(startString, index1 + 1);
            }

            return matched;
        }
```

And using it like this:

```
result = ExtractFromString(this.richTextBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
```

result is a global string var.

The problem is that sometimes it's working fine for the first time but then when i try again another text it's getting stuck inside the while loop nonstop and the program freeze.

Comment: "Sometimes", I love this word. Do you have your bogus input? What is the expected output?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: You haven't actually said what `ExtractFromString` is meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

Code (variant 1, substing between first occurence of `startString` and last occurence of `endString`):

```
private static string ExtractFromString(string text, string startString, string endString)
{
    // argument control
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startString)) throw new ArgumentNullException("startString");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endString)) throw new ArgumentNullException("endString");

    // get index of last occurence of startString and last occurence of endString
    int indexStart = text.IndexOf(startString);
    int indexEnd = text.LastIndexOf(endString);

    // check indexes
    if (indexStart < 0 || indexEnd < 0) return string.Empty;
    indexStart += startString.Length;
    if (indexStart >= indexEnd) return string.Empty;

    // return result
    return text.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart);
}
```

Code (variant 1, substing between first occurence of `startString` and succeeding occurence of `endString`):

```
private static string ExtractFromString(string text, string startString, string endString)
{
    // argument control
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startString)) throw new ArgumentNullException("startString");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endString)) throw new ArgumentNullException("endString");

    // get index of first occurence of startString
    int indexStart = text.IndexOf(startString);
    if (indexStart < 0) return string.Empty;

    // get index of first occurence of endString after startString
    indexStart += startString.Length;
    int indexEnd = text.IndexOf(endString, indexStart);
    if (indexEnd < 0) return string.Empty;

    // return result
    return text.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart);
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = ExtractFromString("x   aaa  some Text  bbb x", "aaa", "bbb");
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it would be good if you fix the OP's code and not change his logic completely.

Comment: @Shaharyar, OP code is invalid, loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Using `LastIndex` can output *different results* in comparison with initial code, e.g. `ExtractString("aaa123bbb456bbb", "aaa", "bbb")`;

Comment: Yet another issue: returning `String.Empty` doesn't allow to distinguish two cases: *no match is found* (e.g. for "aaaxxx") and *empty match* is found (e.g. for "aaabbb")

Comment: In this case, just replace `int indexEnd = text.LastIndexOf(endString);` with `int indexEnd = text.IndexOf(endString, indexStart < 0 ? 0 : indexStart);`

Comment: @General-Doomer: In this case, what if `startString` equals to `stopString` ? E.g. ExtractString("aaa123aaa456aa", "aaa", "aaa")? It seems that your modified code will return an *empty string*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, it is not productoin code to provide all cases and solution, but I added variant for this case.

Comment: `+1` in `text.IndexOf(endString, indexStart + 1)` doesn't save the game: counter example is `ExtractString("aaa123aa", "aaa", "aa")`. Hint: add `Length`